# The print(abhishek.increment) in the last line is not giving the answer I want, can someone tell why?

Tags: python

```
class Employee:
    company = 'Google'

def __init__(self, name, salaryInput, salIncrement):
    self.name = name
    self.salaryInput = salaryInput
    self.salIncrement = salIncrement
    
def salary(self):
    print('Base salary of {} is ${}'.format(self.name, self.salary))
    
def increment(self):
    print('Increment in salary = ${}'.format(self.salIncrement))
    
@property    
def salaryAfterIncrement(self):
    return self.salaryInput + self.salIncrement
    
@salaryAfterIncrement.setter
def salaryAfterIncrement(self, salaryInput):
    self.increment = salaryAfterIncrement - self.salaryInput
    
            
abhishek = Employee('Abhishek', 100, 50)
print(abhishek.salaryAfterIncrement)

print(abhishek.increment)
```

Comment: `abhishek.increment` is a function, you need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parenthesis. And BTW, you need to use return in `.increment()` function. This wouldn't solve your problem but it will print a `None`. So try -

```
return 'Increment in salary = ${}'.format(self.salIncrement)
```

Then use print -

```
print(abhishek.increment())
```

---

Or if you do not want to use return then call the function without print statement -

```
print('Increment in salary = ${}'.format(self.salIncrement))
```

Then call the function -

```
abhishek.increment()
```